# exception handling a constructor

Tags: c++, exception

This was an interview question of me.

Surprisingly i never thought of this kinda question to myself.

can we have exception handling inside a constructor c++?

in tense and not thinking much i said "yes we could probably do it in a constructor.lets say we are allocating some memory using new operator to a pointer member and it throws a bad alloc exception,in this way there is a possibility of exceptions being raised"

Then later i thought that constructors can never return a value.So how can an exception inside a constructor caught.now i am asking this to myself!

can anybody pls help me to come out of this confusion?

Comment: You would catch the exception in the calling code, not in the constructor.

Comment: Exceptions aren't returned in the same way as return values, they skip up the stack to the first appropriate catch block, so whilst you can't return a value from the constructor you can throw an exception from it.

Comment: @Helper Method: If you had allocated memory in the constructor you would definately want to catch the exception in the constructor so that you could de-allocate the memory (then probably re-throw). But its smarter to have the object only dynamically allocate at most one object so you don't need to do this manual type of cleanup.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See this [GOTW Constructor Failures](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) question which addresses your query somewhat and goes on to say it is a waste of time.

Comment: +1 I was going to write about the function-try-block as an option and its many flaws, but I wouldn't get close to Sutter's description :)

Comment: That was a very interesting article, def +1

Answer (score 2):

> Constructors don't have a return type,
>   so it's not possible to use return
>   codes. The best way to signal
>   constructor failure is therefore to
>   throw an exception. If you don't have
>   the option of using exceptions, the
>   "least bad" work-around is to put the
>   object into a "zombie" state by
>   setting an internal status bit so the
>   object acts sort of like it's dead
>   even though it is technically still
>   alive.

You would catch the exception in the calling code, not within the constructor.

See [How can I handle a constructor that fails?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.8) for further details (actually, I'd suggest reading the whole page about exception handling, truly enlightening).

Comment: i read this.but i am expecting some practical methods that people use in such kind of scenarios.

Comment: +1, though one has to say that the question is a bit of a trick question, too. While normally you just throw inside a constructor when it fails in some way, it is perfectly possible to try/catch inside a constructor to handle other failures and avoid failure of said constructor in the first place (or, rethrow). Depending on the situation, this may be preferrable. For example, if you construct two objects in your constructor, and the second one throws bad_alloc, what do you do? Catching the exception in the calling code will leak the first object. Handling inside the constructor avoids this.

Comment: @zombie: what scenarios?  an exception being thrown from a constructor?  A constructor failure?  A constructor catching exceptions?

Comment: The actual question is not how to do it, but whether you should even consider it. It brings more problems than actual solutions. Even in platforms where the compiler did not have proper exception support (in Symbian it would not delete the subobjects of partially constructed objects), exceptions were not banned from constructors, but rather the whole issue was dealt outside of the constructor with two phase initialization (use a `nothrow` constructor and a second initialization function that can throw, and for which you can manage the failure). Then again, it is a pain to work in there.

Comment: @Damon: not if you use smart pointers (and that is the main reason why an object should only manage a single resource). `struct test { std::auto_ptr<int> a,b; type will_throw; test() : a( new int ), b( new int ), will_throw() {} };` -- the destructors of a and b will be called, and they will manage the memory.

Comment: @David: +1: Can not be emphasized enough. Objects should ONLY manage one resource. RAII will then take care of the rest nearly automatically. If you have more than one resource being allocated in the constructor then you need to be very careful making sure the constructor obeys the strong exception guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Exception handling and return type are completely different. when the program find the exception in constructor, it throws the exception to nearly by catch block [if used] or thrown to caller (main()). in this case, we have catch block in constructor and exception handled by it. Once exception handled, the remaining statement in the constructor/function will be started executing. see the below example,

```
class A
{
  public:
   A(){
        printf("Hi Constructor of A\n");        
   try
   {
        throw 10;
   }
   catch(...)
   {
       printf("the String is unexpected one in constructor\n");
   }
   printf("Hi Constructor of A\n");
 }
   ~A(){
   printf("Hi destructor of A\n");
 }
};

int main()
{

try{
    A obj ;
   throw "Bad allocation";
}
catch(int i)
{
    printf("the Exception if Integer is = %d\n", i);
}
 catch(double i)
{
    printf("the Exception if double is = %f\n", i);
}
 catch(A *objE)
{
    printf("the Exception if Object \n");
}
 catch(...)
{
    printf("the Exception if character/string \n");
}
printf("Code ends\n");
return 0;
}
```

This produce Output:

```
 Start: Constructor of A
 the String is unexpected one in constructor
 End: Constructor of A
 Hi destructor of A
 the Exception if character/string 
 Code ends
```

Answer (score -2):

C++ has try-catch clauses similar to those of other languages. A tutorial can be found online: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

EDIT: example turned into fully working code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
  void f(){
    throw 10;
  }

  A(){
    try{
      f();
    }
    catch(int e){
      cout << "Exception caught\n";
    }
  }
};

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  A a;
  return 0;
}
```

This produces output:

```
Exception caught
```

Comment: @laas.i know there are lots of documents.But i am particularly asking about exception handling in a constructor.this doesnt asnwer my question.

Comment: C++ doesn't have `finally` blocks, and exception handling in C++ differs in many ways from languages like Java e.g.. For cleanup, C++ uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: @Helper Method - you are of course right about `finally`, but as I understand it, @zombie asked about exception handling **inside** constructors so my example is still valid or the question should be corrected. I update my answer with more code.

Comment: @zombie - I expanded the example to show exeption handling **inside** constructors. If this is not what you asked, then maybe [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.10) will help as a practical example of cleaning up **after** constructor messed up.